# Change System Language Solaris 8

Tags: solaris, locale

I have Solaris 8 OS installed in French.

Is it possible to switch from French to English without reinstalling the OS ? If yes how ?

When `locale -a` i have this :

```
POSIX
common
en_US.UTF-8
C
iso_8859_1
en_CA
en_CA.ISO8859-1
en_US
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-15
en_US.ISO8859-15@euro
fr_CA
fr_CA.ISO8859-1
iso_8859_15
th
th_TH
th_TH.TIS620
```

Even when I try to edit `/etc/default/init` with :

```
LANG=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_COLLATE=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_CTYPE=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_MONETARY=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_TIME=en_US.ISO8859-15
LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-15
```

and reboot : nothing happens.

To verify the result i always use `date` and when i reboot : i also have the date in french.

P.S : I have to do this configuration in a computer which isn't here in my office, so i have to this manipulation in a an another computer here in my office and if it works, i'll do it to the other computer.

So the computer here is configured in English and i have to switch it to French.
Here is the content of my `~./dt` :

```
C                     errorlog              sessionlogs
Desktop               errorlog.old          sessions
Trash                 errorlog.older        simulateur.dtwmrc
appconfig             help                  startlog
appmanager            icons                 startlog.old
asr.dtwmrc            outils.dtwmrc         startlog.older
bin                   palettes              tmp
bookmarks             sdtfonts              types
dtwmrc                sdtpcaction.conf      wsmenu
en_US.ISO8859-15      sdtpcaction.conf.bak
```

Thanks

Comment: `export LANG=C` ?

Comment: @Archemar thanks for the reply but sorry i didn't understand the answer.
I have to do as a root : `export LANG=C ` and that's all ?

Comment: Please elaborate. "Nothing happens" isn't factual. How are you connecting to that Solaris 8 machine? How are you checking the language setting? What is appearing in French you would like to see in English? What did you change in `/etc/default/init`?

Comment: @jlliagre i edit my question

Comment: How do you connect to the Solaris 8 machine? Through the text console? telnet/ssh? a graphic environment? Under what account? What shell are you using?

Comment: @jlliagre i connect from distance with `Exceed` . in a graphic environment, Under user account and root both, i'm using csh

Comment: @jlliagre can u have an answer for this please : i connect from distance with Exceed . in a graphic environment, Under user account and root both, i'm using csh

Comment: Is the desktop itself displayed in French or English ?

Comment: in French, to try to do the correciton that i want : i'm working in a computer in my office : he's totally in English and if i want to switch it to French i can't do it too

Comment: Don't forget to use (at)jlliagre otherwise I'm not informed of your new comments. Please append the content of you ~/.dtprofile file to your question.

Comment: @jlliagre i edited it with the content of my  `~\home\dt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to the US locale, open with an editor the **file** named `.dtprofile` present in your home directory and add this line at the end:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-15
```

or better:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The desktop, shell and all applications should be displayed in English after the next login.

Answer (score 3):

lang setting is done by `LANG` var.

to change  for current session just enter

```
LANG=C
export LANG
```

for instance (didn't have french installed, so I use portugese)

```
-bash-3.2$ LANG=pt
-bash-3.2$ date
quarta-feira, 29 de março de 2017 12H39m06s UTC
-bash-3.2$ LANG=C
-bash-3.2$ date
Wed Mar 29 12:39:36 UTC 2017
-bash-3.2$
```

- to change only for root, edit `.bashrc` for root, reconnect.
- to change for all users, edit `/etc/login` (or `/etc/profile` )
- to change at system level try editing `/etc/defaults/init`, and reboot.
- by edit, I mean add the two lines in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i don't have `/etc/login` but the real need is to change it at system level so thank you for the answer i'll try it

Comment: it could be `/etc/profile` or `/etc/Profile` I edited my answer.

Comment: And if you don't have the locale you want, you should just be able to install the package vs reinstalling.

Comment: Hi, after trying to edit `/etc/default/init` and reboot : nothing happens. I want to change the `LANG` from `Fr` to `en_US` forever and don't do it every time when i reboot